# emailing the webform's submission values in a table

Tags: webforms

I have been trying to email the submitted values via email handler every time an user submit a form. I have added  on custom body so the submitted values would be in the table formally, but the table is all broken as you can see on the photo. Is there a way to fix the problem? Thank you in advance

Here is what I added on the custom body:

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Account Number</th>
        <th>Current Budget</th>
        <th>New Budget</th>
        <th>Budget Change +/-</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            [webform_submission:values:budget_change_request_form_01_description]
        </td>
        <td>
            [webform_submission:values:acct_]
        </td>
        <td>
            [webform_submission:values: budget_change_request_form_01_current_budget]
        </td>
        <td>
            [webform_submission:values: budget_change_request_form_01_new_budget]
        </td>
        <td>
            [webform_submission:values:budget_change_request_form_01_budget_change_]
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And this is the output of my e-mail

[image]

Comment: Multiple typos (spaces) in the tokens and mustn't it be `[submission:values:...` instead of `[webform_submission:values:...`?

Comment: Ah no, it's just the spaces. See, every values that comes malformed has a space in the token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have spaces in your tokens. Removing those should fix the problem, e.g. this:

```
[webform_submission:values: budget_change_request_form_01_current_budget]
```

should be:

```
[webform_submission:values:budget_change_request_form_01_current_budget]
```

Comment: Wow, what a silly mistake of mine, thanks! However, the table still does not add the borders even after I added in custom css code, or custom body. Would you be able to help with this too?

Comment: Never mind! I think it's because of Outlook I am using that doesn't support fancy e-mails.